# R - Having trouble with caret - "Error in loadNamespace... there is no package called 'recipes' "

Tags: r, package, caret, recipe

I'm trying to run the Box-Cox Transformation function but I keep getting the below error message. Below the code and error I have listed some of the libraries and packages that I've installed to no avail. I'm using Jupyter notebook with R

*Mycode:*

`caret::BoxCoxTrans(mydataframe$mycolumn)`

*The error in the console:*

Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):

there is no package called 'recipes'
Traceback:

1. caret::BoxCoxTrans
2. getExportedValue(pkg, name)
3. asNamespace(ns)
4. getNamespace(ns)
5. loadNamespace(name)
6. namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
   .     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
7. loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
8. withRestarts(stop(cond), retry_loadNamespace = function() NULL)
9. withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1L]])
10. doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)

*I have done the following troubleshooting:*

`install.packages('caret', dependencies = TRUE)`

`install.packages("recipes", dependencies = TRUE)`

`install.packages(c('ddalpha', 'recipes'))`

"Recipes" whatever that is seems to be downloaded as I got the following warning amongst others:
"installation of package 'recipes' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("recipes", dependencies = TRUE):

Help would be very much appreciated I don't know what the problem is

Desired output:

Box-Cox Transformation

xx data points used to estimate Lambda

Input data summary:
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
xx

Largest/Smallest: xx
Sample Skewness: xx

Estimated Lambda: xx

Comment: If the installation of package 'recipes' had non-zero exit status -- then that's where the problem is. What if the full output you get when you run `install.packages("recipes", dependencies = TRUE)`. There is likely a more specific error message in the output than then one you have provided.

Comment: I posted the full output in an "answer" @MrFlick, thanks.